# How to make active AngularJS directive when URL is changed

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS and trying to add a "currentclass" class to my menu 
whenever that tabs content is being displayed. This is what I have so far, 
and it works fine when loading the page

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#/about" class="tab">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/services" class="tab">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
```

---

```
myModule.directive('tab', function($location) {
    var currentPath = "#" + $location.path();
   return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var href = element.attr("href");
            if (currentPath == href)
            {
                element.addClass("currentclass");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This will add the 'currentclass' class to the correct  tag when the page 
   url is #/about or /#services

The problem is if I click the second tab, the class does not get added to 
   it. I imagine I need some way to get the code inside the directive to be 
   re- run when the URL changes. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is bit wrong. It will add "currentClass" class to each tab that is being clicked. Rather than writing logic on "tab" directive, use routeChangeSuccess event. You can set class like `ng-class="{active : activeMenu === item}"`

Here is one [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TtQNQXOLggs1bsYKNJvx?p=preview)